# How to create animated selection of two points just like the app "Measure - Quick Everyday Measurements" does

Tags: java, android, mobile, kotlin

I have to make an app that offers something like the app "Measure - Quick Everyday Measurements" does, regarding the selection of two points in an animated way.

Take a look at the video showing how the app works [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.tango.measure)!

If there is no way to do this by using native code in Android, Can someone tell me which SDK or library could be used to achieve a similar result?

For now, I do not have the need to calculate the line distance (could be a plus). My need is to have something similar in terms of usability.

Comment: It seems like the link you included is not working.  Could you attach a clip of the animation instead?

Comment: That's the link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.tango.measure